# Does un-registering a kindle device remove ebooks downloaded to the device?

Tags: kindle

I would like to know if I can still continue to read my ebooks downloaded to one of my kindle devices, even after unregistering the device from my amazon account?

Can I un-register a kindle device (to test and wanted to know if its safe to do it) and re-register it again?

Appreciate your advise!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an Kindle Fire, no, all purchased content will be removed when you de-register. For an e-ink Kindle, ebooks that have been downloaded will remain on the device until they are removed. Note, however, that this will not necessarily be the case forever.

Comment: What about DRM protected files (i.e. non-free books from Amazon)? Can they still be opened?